# C++ compile time error: expected identifier before numeric constant

Tags: c++, vector, g++

I have read other similar posts but I just don't understand what I've done wrong. I think my declaration of the vectors is correct. I even tried to declare without size but even that isn't working.What is wrong??
 My code is:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector<string> v2(5, "null");
vector< vector<string> > v2d2(20,v2);

class Attribute //attribute and entropy calculation
{
    vector<string> name(5); //error in these 2 lines
    vector<int> val(5,0);
    public:
    Attribute(){}

int total,T,F;

};  

int main()
{  
Attribute attributes;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `5` and `0` in your calls to the `vector` constructor?  Here is what the arguments mean: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

Comment: I was simply trying to use:
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
as your link shows: vector<int> second (4,100);

Comment: @Ajay: terrible notion, the `std` library is part of C++, you should certainly learn to use them together.

Comment: @KillianDS, Libraries aren't part of language (IMO), they are just standardized. `printf` and `cout` are not language concepts, they come from library. And I meant to OP that he/she must learn the basics first!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
vector<string> name(5); //error in these 2 lines
vector<int> val(5,0);
```

in a class outside of a method.

You can initialize the data members at the point of declaration, but not with parenthesis (`()`). Instead, use curly braces (`{}`):

```
class Foo {
    vector<string> name = vector<string>(5);
    vector<int> val{vector<int>(5,0)};
};
```

Before C++11, you need to declare them first, then initialize them e.g in a contructor

```
class Foo {
    vector<string> name;
    vector<int> val;
 public:
  Foo() : name(5), val(5,0) {}
};
```

Comment: Which compiler supports that "C++11" feature ?

Comment: @Ajay GCC since 4.7, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), probably the latest clang. Not sure what the VS release schedule is but I heard the newest version would support all features.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I have GCC 4.6 on Windows, which doesn't support this. VC11 also doesn't support this.

Comment: Could you also explain this: "you cannot do this, in a class OUTSIDE of a method" ? It sounds like we could ONLY IF we do it INSIDE of a method in a class, isn't it? @juanchopanza

Comment: @Jason Inside a method in a class is one of the places where you can do it. You can also do it in a non-member function, or when declaring, for example, a global variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza Got it thank you! May I please also ask why is it not possible to do it for a class variable in a class, while we could for a global variable

Comment: @Jason The idea was to make it impossible to have a situation where declaring a data member could be parsed like a function. Loop up "the most vexing parse".

Comment: Solution worked great for me! In my case, it was an Arduino project where I needed to instantiate an object of a class as a private object of another class, outside a method. I was getting an error with `SoftWire sw (3,4);` although this is the usual way of doing it. Based on the answer given, I tried `SoftWire sw = SoftWire(3, 4);` and it is working great now! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11):

Initializations with `(...)` in the class body is not allowed. Use `{..}` or `= ...`. Unfortunately since the respective constructor is `explicit` and `vector` has an initializer list constructor, you need a functional cast to call the wanted constructor

```
vector<string> name = decltype(name)(5);
vector<int> val = decltype(val)(5,0);
```

As an alternative you can use constructor initializer lists

```
 Attribute():name(5), val(5, 0) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your compiler probably doesn't support all of C++11 yet, which supports similar syntax, you're getting these errors because you have to initialize your class members in constructors:

```
Attribute() : name(5),val(5,0) {}
```

Comment: The provided syntax wouldn't work in `C++11` either, only `brace-or-equal` initialization is allowed when declaring a variable.