# How to create unordered_map of specific size?

Tags: c++, hash

I know we can do this `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map;` 
When I try to look at the size it says `zero` and when I try to look at bucket_count it gives `11`.

What I wanted to do was something like this `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map(1000);`

But I get error `expected identifier before numeric constant`

I want to set the size of the hash table so that I won't have the same problem vector has when vector reallocates memory (copy of the values from old memory location(small) to new memory location (larger)). `Since I have large data of specific size (~100,000) that I want to hash, this motivates me to do preallocation`

When I see unordered_map constructor in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) it expects allocator, hash function etc. Do we really need do provide this much information to just set my hash map to specific size?

Comment: You might be running into the "most vexing parse" problem. Try adding extra parentheses around the `1000`.

Comment: @Dan Yes that worked ... but do you know why this `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map((100))` works and not the other   `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map(100)`

Comment: By the way what you said works only in `gcc version 4.9.3 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0)` then I also tried if single parenthesis work then I found out that also works .. so now I am more  confused because it (both single and double parenthesis) does not work with `gcc 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) for an explanation.

Comment: If you use braces `{}` instead of parentheses it should work all the time.

Comment: @Dan Yes using `{}` it works for both gcc version

Comment: @clcto thank you for your input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with `vector`, you can use `reserve()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve

Comment: I question whether the post envelops sufficient research

Comment: Do you have an answer for why the constructor call does not work?

Comment: @clcto: Because `vector(1000)` actually creates 1000 elements which you can modify later.  What would `unordered_map(1000)` do?  What keys would it use to insert 1000 elements?  It simply cannot have the same semantics.

Comment: @JohnZwinck One overload for the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) takes a `size_type bucket_count` that is the *"minimal number of buckets to use on initialization."*

Comment: @clcto I think what you are saying is only for c++14 .. were you talking about this `unordered_map() : unordered_map( size_type(/*implementation-defined*/) ) {}` ?

Comment: @solti no that one is the default constructor saying the default `bucket_size` is implementation defined. The one directly above or below that, `explicit unordered_map( size_type bucket_count = /*implementation-defined*/, ...` and `explicit unordered_map( size_type bucket_count, ...`, for c++11 and c++14 respectively, but it looks like most overloads take in a `size_type bucket_count`, not just one.

Comment: @clcto so `explicit unordered_map( size_type bucket_count = /*implementation-defined*/,` takes `bucket_count ` as parameter and others `const Hash& hash = Hash(),const KeyEqual& equal = KeyEqual(),const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); ` are defaulted. So shouldn't `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map(1000)` if that is the case (or am I missing something here)... by the way `std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map{1000}` works

Comment: @solti that is my point. The constructor should work, and it did for me [here](http://ideone.com/tOxxrS).

Comment: @solti is it possible you are doing this in a class declaration? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490988/c-compile-time-error-expected-identifier-before-numeric-constant, http://ideone.com/QBdFaO

Comment: @clcto Yes I think you are right ... I do `class A{ public: .. private: std::unordered_map<key, value> my_map(1000);};`

Comment: @solti: Try `my_map{1000}` instead of `my_map(1000)`.

Comment: Yes I used that and it works .. and @clcto helped me find out that this questions was already answered