# Creating vector of sets as a class member gives error in c++

Tags: c++, set

I want to create 9 sets and put them in vector.The following code error outs

```
class X{
   vector<set<int> > rowset(9,set<int>());
};
Line 2: expected identifier before numeric constant
```

Following works ok. But i want to insert empty sets in vector so that i don't have to do a push_back. Please suggest why the above code is erroring out.

```
class X{
   vector<set<int> > rowset;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
vector<set<int> > rowset = vector<set<int> >(9, set<int>());
```

...or that:

```
vector<set<int> > rowset{vector<set<int> >(9, set<int>())};
```

More information on these questions, similar to yours:

- [C++ compile time error: expected identifier before numeric constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490988/c-compile-time-error-expected-identifier-before-numeric-constant)
- [Why can in-class initializers only use = or {}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329962/why-can-in-class-initializers-only-use-or)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
class X{
  X():rowset(9,set<int>()){}
  vector<set<int> > rowset;
};
```