# Avoid race condition performance

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two asynchronous threads (explicitly asked to do it that way) running 2 different methods from an object, `move_robot()` and `get_area()`. The first method moves a vehicle through different positions and the second one calculates the area covered thus far. Both share two object attributes:

```
vector<double> position; // saves current position of the vehicle
bool moving; // true if the vehicle has not reach the end of the path
```

In order to avoid race conditions I am using locks the following way:

```
   void get_area() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); // get mutex
        static vector<double> previous_measure = this->position; // initialized with the first position the robot is in
        lck.unlock();
        while (this->moving) {
            lck.lock();
            auto auxiliar = this->position;
            lck.unlock();
            this->area_covered += distance(auxiliar , previous_measure) * this->width;
            previous_measure = this->position; // save the new position for the next iteration
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10)); // sleep for 10 ms
            std::cout << "Area:" << this->area_covered << " m²" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void next_step() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); // get mutex
        this->position[0] += DT * this->direction[0];
        this->position[1] += DT * this->direction[1];

    }

    void move_robot(const vector<vector<double> > &map) {
    // accumulate the footprint while the robot moves
    // Iterate through the path
        for (unsigned int i=1; i < map.size(); i++) {
            while (distance(position , map[i]) > DISTANCE_TOLERANCE ) {
                this->direction = unitary_vector(map[i], this->position);
                this->next_step();
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10)); // sleep for 10 ms
            }
        }
        this->moving = false; // notify get area to leave
    }
```

In the `get_area()` method I am locking to save the `this->position` attribute in a variable and have the same one over the whole iteration and to initialize the first `previous_measure`. In `next_step()` is used when `this->position` changes according the dynamics of the vehicle.

Moreover, how would you lock the `moving` attribute inside the while condition? And how to avoid this situation: I execute `get_area()`, the robot moves and ends the path and I leave the `get_area` method without doing the last iteration.

My question is **whether it would be possible to optimize this locking and unlocking**, as it is done pretty often (I do not want to set a producer-client structure because I want get_area() to run independent).

---

### EDIT:

I have changed the condition in the while to:

```
bool is_moving() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    return moving;
}



void get_area() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    static vector<double> previous_measure = this->position; 
    lck.unlock();
    while (this->is_moving()) {...}
}
```

But do not know if there is something even cleaner

Comment: The best choise here is to use one thread. But if you are forced to use 2, the most performant approach will be calculating `area_covered` in `move_robot` thread and then syncronize the access only to `area_covered`. This is so because the longest operation (besides sleep and output to console) is copying `position` variable 2 times in `get_area` thread. This copy operation will freeze your `move_robot` thread.

Answer (score 0):

#### Optimization #1: assuming the speed of the robot is slow compared to the speed of computation

Considering the speed of the robot, there is no real need to lock both the `position` and `moving` since the rate of change of this values, compared to the rate of computation will be enormously small, so the margin of error due to `stale` read will be negligible.

In any case the above code is doing exactly that, since the `previous_measure = this->position` is reading the `position` while it's unlocked, therefore there is small chance that `previous_measure != auxiliar` at the end of the loop.

To assure that a final read is executed (meaning `get_area` is computed again after `moving` is false), we can repeat the calculation once more after leaving the loop, since then the robot had stoped moving and the position will never change.

#### Optimization #2: Consumer-Producer communication trough Ring Buffer

In case the speed of change of the variables is close to the speed of computiation, the optimization #1 will obviously create significant error. In such case, you can consider using [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to move the values from `move_robot` to `get_area` without locking. If you have only one consumer and only one producer thread, there is no need to lock. [Here](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/05/17/creating-a-circular-buffer-in-c-and-c/) is an example of implementation of ring buffer (or circular buffer).

Comment: If I add as attribute the ring buffer as:    
```private:
        circular_buffer<vector<double>> position_buffer(20);
```
I get: `error: expected identifier before numeric constant`

If I declare it just as `circular_buffer<vector<double>> position_buffer` and in constructor I do: `position_buffer(20);` gives the error: `error: no match for call to '(circular_buffer<std::vector<double> >) (int)'
`

Comment: You are should initialize the buffer in the constructor (or any other method), not in the declaration, this is why you have the error. Check the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490988/c-compile-time-error-expected-identifier-before-numeric-constant)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you're reading `this->moving` while not holding the lock. This will lead to UB if another thread is also writing it. You can reorder the locking a bit to make it correct, for example like this:

```
   void get_area() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx); // get mutex
        static vector<double> previous_measure = this->position; // initialized with the first position the robot is in
        while (this->moving) {
            auto auxiliar = this->position;
            this->area_covered += distance(auxiliar , previous_measure) * this->width;
            previous_measure = this->position; // save the new position for the next iteration
            lck.unlock();
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10)); // sleep for 10 ms
            std::cout << "Area:" << this->area_covered << " m²" << std::endl;
            lck.lock();
        }
    }
```

Also, `move_robot` must also hold the lock while updating shared values. Just make sure to not hold the lock while sleeping.

```
    void move_robot(const vector<vector<double> > &map) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        for (unsigned int i=1; i < map.size(); i++) {
            while (distance(position , map[i]) > DISTANCE_TOLERANCE ) {
                this->direction = unitary_vector(map[i], this->position);
                this->next_step();
                lck.unlock();
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10)); // sleep for 10 ms
                lck.lock();
            }
        }
        this->moving = false; // notify get area to leave
    }
```

Remember, if writing is involved, then *all* parallel access to a variable must either be protected by a mutex or the variable must be made `atomic`.

Comment: Whta do you think of my EDIT? In order to check the while condition. Furthermore, when setting `this->moving=false` I should consider as well the lock isnt it?

Comment: The edit looks purely aesthetic, apart from extra complication of having to release the lock just to call `is_moving`. And yes, *all* reads and writes must be protected. Don't worry about lock performance - assume the 10ms sleep takes 99.99999% of the total loop time.

Comment: So are you missing a lock in `this->moving=false` ?

Comment: No. Notice the mutex is unlocked only for the sleep. Then it's re-locked.